# how to display text in UIWebVIew

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a NSstring which stores the html text in it.

i want to display this string in uiwebview.

i am using this
**[self.webView loadHTMLString:mystring baseURL:nil]**

i know this is wrong. can anybody tell me how can i display my nsstring in uiwebview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com"]];` should work fine.

make sure the script can access the webView object. :)